# Add a side bar to a list of items to skip to the alphabet selected in SwiftUI

Tags: list, swiftui

I am not sure what the actual term is but please see the screen shot.

I am referring to the A, B, C, D, E,... on the right hand side of the list.

Does anyone know how to make that in SwiftUI?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

DIY!   (copy - paste - test) example

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sel: Int = 0
    let arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".map(String.init)
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("selected: " + arr[sel]).padding().border(Color.red)
            HStack(alignment: .top) {

                // place holder
                Text(arr[sel]).font(.largeTitle).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.1))

                VStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< arr.count) { (i) in
                        Text(self.arr[i]).onTapGesture {
                            self.sel = i
                        }.foregroundColor(Color.blue).padding(.trailing, 5)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]